# Returning text as either Uppercase or Lowercase

Tags: ios, swift

I'm pretty new to Swift, so the thing is that I have an Enum and I have to return text with either Uppercase or Lowercase letters, and my code doesn't work.

```
enum UpLow {
    case Uppercase
    case Lowercase

    func setCase(text: String) -> String {
        switch self {
        case .Uppercase:
            return text.uppercased()

        case .Lowercase:
            return text.lowercased()
        }
    }
    setCase(text: "example", case: .Uppercase)
}
```

and the error I get:

Playground execution failed:

error: demo.playground:60:5: error: expected declaration
    setCase(text: "example", case: .Uppercase)
    ^

demo.playground:47:6: note: in declaration of 'UpLow'
enum UpLow {
     ^

Edit: I have to get this thing to work only by calling that function setCase(text: "Chosen text", case: .ChosenCase)

Exercise 5a:
Create a function and an enum allows you to define this method:
setCase (text: "Interstellar", case: .Uppercase) // INTERSTELLAR
setCase (text: "Interstellar", case: .Lowercase) // interstellar
* /

Comment: Unrelated to your issue but it is standard practice to start case names with lowercase letters. So change `Uppercase` to `uppercase` and `Lowercase` to `lowercase`.

Comment: Then I get this error:

Playground execution failed:

error: demo.playground:61:2: error: use of unresolved identifier 'setCase'
 setCase(text: "example", case: .Uppercase)
 ^~~~~~~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes no sense to put the function into the enum and according to Exercise 5a it's not required.

```
enum UpLow {
    case uppercase
    case lowercase
}

func setCase (text: String, `case`: UpLow) -> String {
    switch `case` {
    case .uppercase: return text.uppercased()
    case .lowercase: return text.lowercased()
    }
}

let uppercaseString = setCase(text: "Interstellar", case: .uppercase)
let lowercaseString = setCase(text: "Interstellar", case: .lowercase)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `setCase(text: String) -> String` is an instance method of the `UpLow` enum. That means that in order to call it, you need to call it on a receiver, which is a variable of type `UpLow`. For example, `UpLow.Uppercase.setCase(text: "Chosen Text")`

Furthermore, the function you're trying to call is the global function `setCase(text:case:)`, which doesn't exist.

Unlike a global function, an instance method has an "instance" associated with it. This is the `self` variable, which acts like an implicit parameter that's made available to you within the body of the method.

A further issue that your call to `setCase(text: "example", case: .Uppercase)` was done within the declaration of `UpLow`. This is invalid. A declaration is like an abstract set of definitions. It's not "run" top to bottom the way the rest of a playground is.

You have several ways of fixing this.

1. You can keep `setCase` as an instance method, in which case you would use like:

   ```
   enum UpLow {
       case uppercase
       case lowercase

       func setCase(text: String) -> String {
           switch self {
           case .uppercase: return text.uppercased()
           case .lowercase: return text.lowercased()
           }
       }
   }

   UpLow.uppercase.setCase(text: "example")
   ```
2. You can create a global function instead (this is the worst choice, IMO):

   ```
   enum UpLow {
       case uppercase
       case lowercase
   }

   func setCase(text: String, case upLow: UpLow) -> String {
       switch upLow { // Note: there is no "self" in a global function
       case .uppercase: return text.uppercased()
       case .lowercase: return text.lowercased()
       }
   }

   setCase(text: "Chosen text", case: .ChosenCase)
   ```
3. Or my favourite, make your function as an instance method on `String` itself:

   ```
   enum UpLow {
       case uppercase
       case lowercase
   }

   extension String
       func setCase(_ upLow: UpLow) -> String {
           // "self" is the String, "upLow" is the UpLow
           switch upLow { 
           case .uppercase: return self.uppercased()
           case .lowercase: return self.lowercased()
           }
       }
   }

   "example".setCase(.uppercase)
   ```